# Kotlin Spring Boot Test

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, unit-testing

I am using Gradle, Kotlin V1.9.21 (in my opinion is the version irrelevant) and Spring Boot V3.2.0. As a starter I am using only Spring Batch:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch'
```

I have a test class (integration test) with a `@Value` annotated member variable:

```
class TeamPluginHelperTests
{
    @Value("\${app.jira.user}")
    private lateinit var jiraUser: String
```

I am using the following test frameworks:

```
testImplementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test'
```

When I look at the loaded libraries, I find

```
org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.9.3
```

but also

```
junit:junit:4.13.2
```

Junit 4 comes from

```
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.9.21
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.9.21 (*)
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:1.9.21
|         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:1.9.21 (*)
|         \--- junit:junit:4.13.2
|              \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3 -> 2.2
|                   \--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.2
```

Now my question: how should I annotate the class `TeamPluginHelperTests` to get the values annotated member variables initialised in the most efficient way (as minimal as possible)?

First thought was

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension::class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=[TeamPluginHelperTests::class])
```

because with Junit 5 you have to use `ExtendWith` instead of `RunWith`. However, the variable is not initialised and I receive a

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property jiraUser has not been initialized
```

When I use

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner::class)
@SpringBootTest(classes=[TeamPluginHelperTests::class])
```

everything works fine, but I thought `SpringRunner` should only be used with Junit4. So can someone explain me what is happening here and why `ExtendWith` is not working?

Comment: Probably because your `@Test` is from JUnit and not JUnit5. Spring Boot 3 doesn't include jUnit4 afaik (not by default). Also the `@SpringBootTest` is already annotated with `@ExtendWIth` so you don't need the annotation. I would suggest to figure out where JUnit4 is coming from and exclude it. FInally the value in your `classes` doesn't make sense either, remove it.

Comment: Added the dependency tree. Test is available for JUnit4 (`org.junit.Test`) and JUnit5 (`org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`) as well as for Kotlin Test (`kotlin.test.Test`) - but you are right I was using the JUnit4 annotation.

Comment: So kotlin-test depends on junit4. Weird that that still uses an old dependency. But nonentheless using JUnit5 bootrstrapping with a JUnit4 test will not work, the other way around won't work either. For safety you might want to replace `kotlin-test` with `kotlin-test-junit5` which doesn't have JUnit4 but JUnit5. This will prevent you selecting the wrong combinations.

Comment: Used `kotlin.test.Test`, removed JUnit4 , removed SpringRunner, removed ExtendWith. Understood everything, works now. Thanks a lot! Would accept this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is mixing JUnit4 with JUnit5 in a single test. When using the `@Test` from JUnit4 the `@ExtendWith` doesn't do anything as that is from JUnit5.

The same applies for the other way around when using `@RunWith` with the JUnit5 setup.

I would recommend to use `kotlin-test-junit5` in favor of `kotlin-test` which will pull in JUnit5 and not JUnit4. This will prevent you from mixing classes and annotations from JUnit4 in a JUnit5 test.

Additionally the `@ExtendWith` isn't strictly necessary as the `@SpringBootTest` itself is also annotated with `@ExtendWith`.